# Simple Join Query Execution Time v/s Materialized View execution Time

Tags: oracle, join, materialized-views, execution-time

I am looking for performance improvement of SQL (ORACLE)
Based on few examples I tried to compare execution time between simple join between two tables v/s same query with MatrializedView.

Both execution time is almost same.

TableA Join TableB

V/s

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW emp_mv
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE
ON DEMAND
AS (QUERY TableA Join TableB)

both sqls are running for 7m for 1000 records.

total we have 14k Records in Table A and 50 recoreds in Table B , final output with 14K records

Is there anything which I am missing regarding performance of query execution?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect the same query to act differently?

Materialized view's benefit might come later, when you actually start using data it contains because you already *pre-processed* it and prepared for future use. You could use the same query (with the join) over and over again and it'll take more or less the same time (disregard caching). But, if you store that query's data into a materialized view (and properly index it), data retrieval might/should be faster.

That's kind of "opposite" of creating an *ordinary view* which doesn't contain any data - it is just a *stored query* and it retrieves data every time you select from it, performing the same join all over again.

Materialized view *contains data*, just as if it were a table. It helps a lot if data is stored in tables you access over database links - that might be, and usually is, slow. But, if you create a materialized view (during night/off hours), you have data available to you much faster. It won't help much if data in tables change frequently because you'll have to refresh the MV frequently as well (usually ON COMMIT), but - if tables are really large, you have a complex query, then refreshing might also take some (a lot of?) time.